# Is it possible to create a frame from a tkinter window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I was looking for a long time for an analog clock on the Internet, which really works. Now I have found a clock and made some adjustments. If you run the code as it is now, it opens in a new window, but it is possible to save this clock in a frame. I have tried for a long time, but I can not do it. Now my question how do I do this the easiest way?
Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as Tkinter

import math
import time

from PIL import Image





class create_clock(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, size):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self)
        image = Image.open("clock-v2.gif")
        image = image.resize((size, size), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        image.save(fp="data/Widgets/Clock/Clock_sizes/acc.png")

        self.size = size
        self.x = size/2  # Center Point x
        self.y = size/2   # Center Point
        self.length = (size/2)*0.75  # Stick Length
        self.creating_all_function_trigger()

    # Creating Trigger For Other Functions
    def creating_all_function_trigger(self):
        self.create_canvas_for_shapes()
        self.creating_background_()
        self.creating_sticks()
        return

    # Creating Background
    def creating_background_(self):
        self.image = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file ='data/Widgets/Clock/Clock_sizes/acc.png')
        self.canvas.create_image(self.size/2, self.size/2, image=self.image,)

        return

    # creating Canvas
    def create_canvas_for_shapes(self):
        self.canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(self,  bg ='#1E1E1E')
        self.canvas.pack(expand='yes', fill='both')
        return


    def creating_sticks(self):
        self.sticks = []
        for i in range(3):
            if i == 1:
                store = self.canvas.create_line(self.x, self.y, self.x + self.length*1.066666666666667, self.y + self.length*1.066666666666667, width=5, fill='#6D6D6D')
                self.sticks.append(store)

            elif i == 0:
                at = self.length -100
                store = self.canvas.create_line(self.x, self.y, self.x + at, self.y + at, width=5,
                                                fill='#6D6D6D')
                self.sticks.append(store)
            elif i == 2:
                store = self.canvas.create_line(self.x, self.y, self.x + self.length*1.066666666666667, self.y + self.length*1.066666666666667, width=1.5,
                                                fill='orange')
                self.sticks.append(store)



        return

    # Function Need Regular Update
    def update_class(self):
        now = time.localtime()

        t = time.strptime(str(now.tm_hour), "%H")
        hour = int(time.strftime("%I", t)) * 5 + (now.tm_min*0.0833333333333333)




        now = (hour, now.tm_min, now.tm_sec)


        for n, i in enumerate(now):
            x, y = self.canvas.coords(self.sticks[n])[0:2]
            cr = [x, y]

            if n == 1:
                cr.append((self.length +0)* math.cos(math.radians(i * 6) - math.radians(90)) + self.x)
                cr.append((self.length + 0) * math.sin(math.radians(i * 6) - math.radians(90)) + self.y)
            elif n == 0:
                cr.append((self.length *0.6666) * math.cos(math.radians(i * 6) - math.radians(90)) + self.x)
                cr.append((self.length *0.6666) * math.sin(math.radians(i * 6) - math.radians(90)) + self.y)
            elif n == 2:
                cr.append((self.length*1.066666666666667) * math.cos(math.radians(i * 6) - math.radians(90)) + self.x)
                cr.append((self.length*1.066666666666667) * math.sin(math.radians(i * 6) - math.radians(90)) + self.y)




            self.canvas.coords(self.sticks[n], tuple(cr))
        return








root = create_clock(size=200
)

while True:
    root.update()
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.update_class()
```

Comment: Have you tried inheriting from `Tkinter.Frame` instead of `Tkinter.Tk`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried. It just opens a blank window

Comment: Well, you have also call `pack`, `place` or `grid` on it just like with any other frame.

Comment: Ow true, you are right. Now I have a question again (:  In the while loop at the very end how can I call the function update_class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inherit from `Frame` instead of `Tk`. You then need to call `pack`, `place`, or `grid` to add the frame to a window.

```
class create_clock(Tkinter.Frame):
    def __init__(self, size):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self)
        ...

root = Tkinter.Tk()
clock = create_clock(size=200)
clock.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

I would also recommend calling the class `Clock` rather than `create_clock` since you're creating a clock object rather than a function.

The last block in your code needs to be modified. Using a while loop like you are doing is not very efficient and should be avoided. Instead, you can write that last block like this:

```
def update_every_second():
    clock.update_class()
    clock.after(1000, update_every_second)

update_every_second()
root.mainloop()
```